# How to create ORM across multiple different SQL Databases in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, eclipselink

Is there any kind of Java based open source technology out there that allows me to create an **object-relational mapping** where the underlying **data is spread across different SQL databases** on different servers.

Important: **Read** and **write** operations should be possible.

I looked into hibernate but couldn't find any information whether  this kind of scenario is possible or not.

### Example

#### Relational Data

```
DatabaseA.Persons               DatabaseB.ContactDetails
+-------+-------------------+   +----------+-------------------+
| Name  |       Email       |   |  Phone   |       Email       |
+-------+-------------------+   +----------+-------------------+
| John  | john@example.org  |   | 555-0100 | john@example.org  |
| Jenny | jenny@example.org |   | 555-0200 | jenny@example.org |
+-------+-------------------+   +----------+-------------------+
```

#### Object-Relational Mapping

```
Class: Persons                   Class: ContactDetails
 + Field: Name                    + Field: Phone
 + Field: Email                   + Field: Email
 + Field: ContactDetails           

 ContactDetailsRelation: Persons.Email -> ContactDetails.Email
```

#### Fictive Usage

```
myCustomer.getName()
myCustomer.getEMail()
myCustomer.getContactDetails().getEMail()
myCustomer.getContactDetails().getPhone()

myCustomer.setName("Max")
myCustomer.setEMail("max@example.org")
myCustomer.getContactDetails().setEMail("max@example.org")
myCustomer.getContactDetails().getPhone("555-0300")

myCustomer.setContactDetails(myOtherContactDetails)
```

Comment: it is possible in hibernate

Comment: it is possible in pretty much all ORMs ... JPA API, JDO API, and the implementations of them!

Comment: after a little bit of research, I found out, that the problem I'm trying to solve seems to be called "vertical partitioning" ... and the only framework I could find that might be useful is EclipseLink with its "CompositePersistenceUnits" or alternatively with its "@PinnedPartitioning" annotation ... sadly, there is not much documentation.  .. I couldn't find a way to do this with JPA ...am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
    **This is exactly what you do.**

 1. You need two hibernate configuration files. You'll need to call them hibernate_sql.cfg.xml and hiberante_oracle.cfg.xml or something like that to differentiate them.
 2. when you initialized your Configuration object, you specifiy the name of the config files. So, you'll have two Configuration objects, from which you'll get two SessionFactory objects.
 3. There you provide the appropriate database connecton config, the dialect to use and which hbm or annotation mapping files for the Entity classes are needed and so on.
 4. within in code you create a single SessionFactory for each database.



    SessionFactory oracleSF = Configuration.configure("hibernate_sql.cfg.xml").buildSessionFfactory();

    SessionFactory msSF = Conf..configure("hiberante_oracle.cfg.xml").build....
```

Comment: Thanks but I cant see how this will help me to build relations from entities in one SessionFactory to entities in the other SessionFactory. I figured out that EclipseLink with CompositePersistenceUnits or @PinnedPartitioning might do the trick. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hard to imagine real-life JPA solution over two PU (sessions etc). I see one possible option: loose coupled, to be true almost independent parts (like bookkeeping / crm in old architecure systems)